# Is there a way to create Labels longer than 40 characters on CUSTOM OBJECTS?

Tags: custom-object, customlabel, label

Are there really no valid workarounds for enabling labels on Custom Objects to be longer than 40 characters (in Lightning)?   I'm on the 3rd project where there was a valid business reason for needing this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have over 40 characters for a custom object/field Label at the moment.

Here's a Salesforce Idea you can upvote - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Y2HMAA0